# Agregar objetos de diferentes clases a un ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, array, netbeans, java-ee, jasper-reports

tengo un problema al agregar objetos a un arraylist.
Tengo la siguiente linea de codigo:
List data = new ArrayList();

a esta lista quiero agruegarle los datos de diferentes clases, para pasar después esta lista como un datasource a ireport.

```
            ContactoServer contactos=null;

            for(ContactoServer t : map.getContactoServer()){    
            contactos = new ContactoServer();
            contactos.setNmContacto(t.getNmContacto());
            contactos.setTelContacto(t.getTelContacto());
            contactos.setCelContacto(t.getCelContacto());
            contactos.setCorreoContacto( t.getCorreoContacto());
            data.add(contactos); 
            }
```

Aqui me agrega sin problemas los contactos de la clase ContactoServer sin ningún problema, pero cuando le paso los siguientes datos de otra clase "ListServer", el arrayList genera conflicto al pasarlo como datasource.

```
            ListServer lServidores = null;
            for(ListServer listServ : listarServidores.getListServer()){
                lServidores = new ListServer();
                lServidores.setNmIpnat(listServ.getNmIpnat());
                data.add(lServidores);
```

}

Como hago para agregarle esto al data.

### Espero me puedan ayudar, paso el código completo:

@WebServlet(name = "ServletJsonToMap", urlPatterns = {"/ServletJsonToMap"})
public class ServletJsonToMap extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ParseException {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    //deserializo el json
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

    try
    {           
        JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/prueba.jasper"));
        HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
       // mapeamos el json que se captura por URL https://api.myjson.com/bins/2y29g
       UserClass mapInf = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2fw0y"), UserClass.class);
       UserClass listarServidores = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2fw0y"), UserClass.class);
       Server map = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2fw0y"), Server.class);           

        List data = new ArrayList();


        //Pasamos los parametros a mostrar - Información general de la empresa 
          if(mapInf != null){
          parametros.put("infoEmpNmEmpresa", mapInf.getInfoEmpNmEmpresa());
          parametros.put("tipoIdentificacionEmp", mapInf.getTipoIdentificacionEmp());
          parametros.put("infoEmpNumeroIdentificacion", mapInf.getInfoEmpNumeroIdentificacion());            
          parametros.put("infoEmpDireccion", mapInf.getInfoEmpDireccion());
          parametros.put("departamento", mapInf.getDepartamento());
          parametros.put("ciudad", mapInf.getCiudad());
          parametros.put("infoEmpTelefono", mapInf.getInfoEmpTelefono());
          parametros.put("infoEmpCel", mapInf.getInfoEmpCel());
          parametros.put("infoEmpCorreo", mapInf.getInfoEmpCorreo());              
          parametros.put("infoLegalNmEmpresa", mapInf.getInfoLegalNmEmpresa());
          parametros.put("tipoIdentificacionLegal", mapInf.getTipoIdentificacionLegal());
          parametros.put("infoLegalNumeroIden", mapInf.getInfoLegalNumeroIden());
          parametros.put("infoLegalDireccion", mapInf.getInfoLegalDireccion());
          parametros.put("infoLegalTelefono", mapInf.getInfoLegalTelefono());
          parametros.put("infoLegalCel", mapInf.getInfoLegalCel());
          parametros.put("infoLegalCorreo", mapInf.getInfoLegalCorreo());              
          parametros.put("tipoCuenta", mapInf.getTipoCuenta());
          parametros.put("infoComiNumCta", mapInf.getInfoComiNumCta());
          parametros.put("txtArea", mapInf.getTxtArea());

          //Parametros envio y recepcion pagos
          parametros.put("formatoTipoPago", mapInf.getFormatoTipoPago());
          parametros.put("formatoTipoPagoRecp", mapInf.getFormatoTipoPagoRecp());
          parametros.put("tipoRespuesta", mapInf.getTipoRespuesta());
          parametros.put("radioRes", mapInf.getRadioRes());
          parametros.put("radioResCuentas", mapInf.getRadioResCuentas());
          parametros.put("checkConsolidadoPagos", mapInf.getCheckConsolidadoPagos());
          parametros.put("selectRecep", mapInf.getSelectRecep());
          parametros.put("radioResContenidoRespuesta", mapInf.getRadioResContenidoRespuesta());
          parametros.put("periosidadEnvio", mapInf.getPeriosidadEnvio());
          parametros.put("checkConsolidadoCuentas", mapInf.getCheckConsolidadoCuentas());
          parametros.put("nmMinutos", mapInf.getNmMinutos());
          parametros.put("minutosDos", mapInf.getMinutosDos());
          parametros.put("txtAreaObservaciones", mapInf.getTxtAreaObservaciones());

          for(CuentasEstado ce: mapInf.getCuentasEstados()){
              parametros.put("contenidoRespuesta", ce.getLabel());
             }
          for(ListaResp lr: mapInf.getListaResp()){
              parametros.put("listaRespuestas", lr.getLabel());
              }
        }

          // se recorre el objecto contacServer del Json
         if(map != null){
            ContactoServer contactos=null;
            for(ContactoServer t : map.getContactoServer()){    
                 contactos = new ContactoServer();
            contactos.setNmContacto(t.getNmContacto());
            contactos.setTelContacto(t.getTelContacto());
            contactos.setCelContacto(t.getCelContacto());
            contactos.setCorreoContacto( t.getCorreoContacto());
            data.add(contactos); 
            }

         } 
          //parametros servidor
         if(listarServidores != null){
              int contador=0;
            // se leen los contactos técnicos   
                ListServer lServidores = null;
            for(ListServer listServ : listarServidores.getListServer()){
                lServidores = new ListServer();
                lServidores.setNmIpnat(listServ.getNmIpnat());
                data.add(lServidores);


          contador ++;
          //data.add(contador);
         }
        }

        //Se muestra el reporte 
         JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data));
         //JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, new JREmptyDataSource());

        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
        exporter.exportReport();
    }
    catch (IOException | JRException e)
    {
    }

}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
       // Logger.getLogger(ServletJsonToMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServletJsonToMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

private static class YAMLFactory extends JsonFactory {

    public YAMLFactory() {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Victor, por que no lo manejas como subreporte así podrás enviar el datasource con ContactoServer y en el subreporte envías los ListServer,

Comment: Hola @Ajeno, de hecho manejo el ContactoServer y el ListServer como subreportes y desde el reporte principal los invoco, pero no he logrado que reciba dichos datos ya que desde el servlet en el data (ArrayList) me genera conflicto cuando agrego el ListServer.

Comment: YO tambien tengo el mismo problema, son dos clases de la misma clase padre hice un arraylist de la clase padre pero ahora, solo quiero sacar los elementos de una sola de las subclases

Comment: @katiuska si tienes una nueva pregunta, crea una nueva pregunta (con una descripción del problema, el código que tengas y las dificultades con las que te encuentres, como se describe en [ask]). No publiques respuestas que realmente deberían ser preguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te manda error porque es un objeto diferente al que ya tiene guardado, deberías guardarlo en dos listas diferentes por ejemplo:

```
List<ContactoServer> data1 = new ArrayList();
List<ListServer> data2 = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, ya intente hacer así, pero necesito pasarle un datasource al reporte, como podria agrupar data1, data2, data.. en uno solo:                                                                                     JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data))

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con la clase _Object_ te dejo dos links, en lo que explican:

Comment: (http://rootear.com/desarrollo/poo-clase-object-java) y (http://dis.um.es/~bmoros/Tutorial/parte5/cap5-10.html)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una `interface` y todos tus objetos lo implementen

```
public interface IObject { }
public class ContactoServer implements IObject { }
public class ListServer implements IObject { }

List<IObject> lista = new ArrayList<IObject>();
```

El objeto `lista` de tipo `List<Iobject>` aceptara cualquier objeto que implemente `IObject`